# uwp app file assosiation directory is invalid error

Tags: xaml, uwp, windows-10, file-permissions, file-association

I have my video player app with **File Assosiation** feature, so when I double click a video file in my File explorer it gets opened in my app, it works most of the time, but sometimes for unknown reason it gives me following error.

> Directory is invalid

note that this error is not within the app or any exception the error occurs within a dialog of windows explorer, and I tried to open the same file with **Movies and TV** app instead, and it was succesfully opened in that.

> I have attached the screenshot of the error.

[image: error]

Comment: Is there any relevance with the file location and the file type? How do you handle the activated event in the `OnFileActivated` method of your app? Could you provide more detail info to help reproduce this issue?

Comment: @BreezeLiu-MSFT I just get the files and play them in my app in fileactivation, I am doing that perfectly because I can play almost everyfile, but rarely I get this error, and my app doesnt even try to launch this error is outside the scope of my application, so I think my code doesnt effect this error.

Comment: It is hard to say what it the reason, it would be better for troubleshooting the issue if you can provide a minimal reproducible sample to help us see this issue.